# Is there any software or tools for the cassandra GUI？

Tags: database, cassandra

I found it not convenient to do CURD operation in command line.

Comment: I just want to find a sutiable GUI tools for Cassandra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about ops center? You can see it here.
http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-opscenter

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will make a try.

Comment: I was able to install the ops center, but I found that it cannot add column or data into the keyspace, is there someting wrong happened when I install the software?

Comment: At last ,I found that Cassandra-Cluster-Admin is vey cool for CRUD in Cassandra, you can have a try

Answer (score 1):

When I work with cassandra I use OpsCenter for administrative tools, and I use Astyanax from Netflix as framework to write CRUD operations in java.

Comment: At last ,I found that Cassandra-Cluster-Admin is vey cool for CRUD in Cassandra, you can have a try.